# ImportError: No module named rest_framework_extensions.cache.mixins

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to set up RDMO on a apache server, but when running "python manage.py runserver" this error accures. Before that many other import Error accurred which I solved by pip install missing package, but i am not able to find requred package to solve this error.

And it would also be very helpful if someone can provide name to the whole package/bundle required for RDMO server run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to install [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions) package

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.  :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to do,

```
pip install drf-extensions
```

its because of **drf-extensions** missing.. install it will fix